# Django FormSets: How to eliminate additional queries on is_valid() and save()?

Tags: django

I am POSTing back to a FormSet. The Django debug toolbar is showing me that for both is_valid() and save(), every Model in the queryset is being re-queried, even though they have all already been retrieved from database during construction of the FormSet. No special object associations here.

E.g. A user has 5 domains. This will issue 1 + 5 + 5 queries == 11 queries. How can I eliminate the last 10 of these queries?

Versions:

- Python 2.7.5
- Django 1.6.1

models.py

```
class Domain(Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'domain'
```

forms.py

```
class DomainForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Domain

DomainFormSet = modelformset_factory(Domain, form=DomainForm, extra=0)

class DomainFormSetWithQuerySet(DomainFormSet):
    def __init__(self, user, data=None):
        super(DomainFormSetWithQuerySet, self).__init__(data, prefix='domains', queryset=Domain.objects.filter(user=user))
```

views.py

```
def view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        domain_formset = DomainFormSetWithQuerySet(request.user, request.POST)

        // One big select query:
        // select * from domains where user_id = ? order by id asc
        //
        // Then, an additional select query for each form in the formset:
        // select * from domains where domain_id = ?
        if domain_formset.is_valid():

            // An additional select query for each form in the formset:
            // select * from domains where domain_id = ?
            domain_formset.save()
```